# Reading triple nested for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested

My code is as follows. My confusion occurs during the 2nd and 3rd loop. Why does the result return 1*** then 12** then 123* then 1234.. I get the j loop is reset to 0 but doesn't it reenter the k loop whenever its true that j<=i?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        cout << j;
    for(int k = 4 - i; k >= 1; k--)
        cout << "*";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the result be something like 1*** then 1**2 then 1*23 and then 1234?

Comment: Your loop is not triple nested, both the j and k loop are nested in the i loop. If this was triple nested the k loop would be nested in the j loop.

Comment: Yeah I was confused on that I thought it was but realized that they're 2 separate loops

Answer (score 3):

### Some clarification first:

Firstly:  j is never reset to 0, but to 1.

Secondly: This is imho no triple-nested for-loop, which was be (but is not needed to have your code working as you describe it):

```
for(...) {
    for(...) {
        for(...) { 
        }
    }
}
```

### To your confusion:

Pretty printing your code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    // Write the digits 1..i (1, 12, 123, 1234)
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        std::cout << j;
    }

    // Write the stars (***, **, *)
    for(int k=(4-i); k>=1; k--) {
        std::cout << "*";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Imagine the following sequences:

```
// Iteration  | i | j | k | String
// 1          | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1*
// 2          | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1**
// 3          | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1***\n
// 4          | 2 | 1 | - | 1
// 5          | 2 | 2 | - | 12
// 6          | 2 | 2 | 2 | 12*
// 7          | 2 | 2 | 1 | 12**\n
// 8          | 3 | 1 | - | 1
// 9          | 3 | 2 | - | 12
// 10         | 3 | 3 | - | 123
// 11         | 3 | 3 | 1 | 123*\n
// 12         | 4 | 1 | - | 1
// 13         | 4 | 2 | - | 12
// 14         | 4 | 3 | - | 123
// 15         | 4 | 4 | - | 1234\n
```

The k-loop is reentered, if the initial index:

```
// k:=(4-i) >= 1
```

So entering the k-Loop is exclusively dependent on the index i.

Mathematically:

```
//         (4-i) >= 1
// <=>    -i >= (1-3)
// <=>    -i >= -3
// <=>     i <= 3
```

So the k-loop is reentered, as long as i is <= 3.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the effect you want your code should be like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {   
        cout << j;
        for(int k = 4 - i; k >= 1; k--)
            cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

if you dont have the {} the k loop is executed only after finishing the j loop